# Autoloading and Zeitwerk Mode in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Is any of this code depreciated in Zeitwerk Mode in Rails 6?

```
 class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.2

    # config/application.rb
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join("config", "locales", "**", "*.{rb,yml}")]
    config.i18n.fallbacks = true

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.
    config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/app/queries/"]


    # https://gist.github.com/maxim/6503591 (should remove this and fix)
    config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("lib")
```

I read that autoloading is being removed, and so far it has not caused an issue but wanted to remove deprecated code. If it is depreciated, how do I load my code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nothing you have here is deprecated, however one thing worth mentioning is from the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html):

> The array of autoload paths can be extended by mutating config.autoload_paths, in config/application.rb, but nowadays this is discouraged.

Rails 5+ is discouraging the use of manually extending *config.autoload_paths* because of potential issues it can cause in your production environment. The discussion dates back to 2013 and you can read about it [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13142).

From Rails 5+ all directories under *app/* are autoloaded by default. If you'd like to follow the Rails recommendation, you should remove this line

```
config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/app/queries/"]
```

and move your queries directory under *"#{Rails.root}/app"* folder.